# How do you record "window close" transaction in LoadRunner?

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I am trying to record a script for an IBM BPM application that opens up a popup window and accepts some data; once done I click on a Submit button after which it closes the window. However I am unable to capture the transaction in LoadRunner.

I am using the IE 8 browser and VUGen 11.52.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to record a modal dialog event which has no communication to a server while the dialog is open then you need to use a development model which exercises the full gui front end instead of operating at the protocol level.  So, this would be a GUI virtual user, a Citrix Virtual User or an RDP Virtual User.

The operative element here is that if you are recording at the protocol level and the dialog never has an interaction with the protocol, then you should not expect to see anything recorded.   **Think Architecturally!**